# Vue data value life lifecycle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hove i set this.url value before application create metod is run.
When i bind videoSrcMp4 property with url data, its null, because created function is runing after application set url to null.

How i set this.url before created funcion is runing.

```html
<vue-video-background v-bind:videoSrcMp4="url"></vue-video-background>

<script>
  import VueVideoBackground from 'vue-video-background'
  export default {
    name: 'name_component',
    components: {
      VueVideoBackground
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        count: 1,
        url: 'null',
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      let html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')
      html[0].classList.add('app-single')

      this.count = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1
      let url = '../path/to/video/file' + this.count + '.mp4'
      console.log(url)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The `created` hook runs before the elements defined in the template are mounted. So, just putting `this.url = url` at the end of your `created` hook will set the `url` property before the `vue-video-background` component takes in the value as its `videoSrcMp4` prop.

Comment: Omg. I forgot set this.url to url omg... Tnx man...